# Should I Have to Wait After Creating Team with Graph

Tags: c#, azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I am using the MS Graph API from our web app to create an MS Teams Team in clients' systems and setup a few folders. But I will randomly get errors if I don't impose a hard-coded wait after creating the team. I call the following endpoints in the order shown:

```
//Create new Team and get basic info
POST teams
GET teams/{team-id}/primaryChannel
GET teams/{team-id}
GET teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/filesFolder

//Sometimes unknown users must be invited to join org as guest
POST invitations

//Everyone but the owner is added as a guest
POST teams/{team-id}/members

//This is done in a batch, because there is one folder per team guest + one for owner
POST groups/{team-id}/drive/items/{channel-folder-id}/children

//Team members' folders are permitted to them only. So all permissions are deleted and a single user added back
GET groups/{folder-id}/drive/items/{folder-id}/permissions
DELETE groups/{team-id}/drive/items/{folder-id}/permissions/{permission-id}
POST groups/{folder-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/invite
```

I will sporadically get Forbidden and/or Bad Request responses from:

```
POST teams/{team-id}/members
DELETE - groups/{team-id}/drive/items/{item-id}/permissions/{permission-id}
```

Obviously the return statuses of 403 are bugs, because the app definitely has permission to perform the action.

Imposing a 60 second wait after creating the Team seems to resolve this. However, I am currently testing on our Teams environment and am concerned that clients with larger Teams setups will require a longer wait period. I've seen other areas where the documentation says you should wait up to 15 minutes before using a Team that was created from a Group (I am not sure if this applies to creating a normal Team though).

Does anyone know what kind of latency I should be prepared for generally, and if there is any endpoint I can ping to see if the Team is ready for use?

Comment: You could use the POST and DELETE that you want to do as the ping.  Try it, if it fails, wait (with `await`) a bit, try again.  Don't wait a full 60 seconds, wait 5 or 10 seconds.  One thing you could try is to see if a GET of that resource fails when the POST or DELETE fails.  If it does, use that as the ping.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Azure AD, Teams and Exchange are all different systems and need some kind of synchronization that sometimes needs some time.

Whenever you're going to create something in one of these systems, be prepared that it takes some time to access it.

One of the most awkward behaviour I came across is, when you create a group through Exchange Remote Powershell you'll get instantly the group object back. This object has an Azure Object ID. But if you immediately go to Graph and make a request for that group you'll get a 404. Also a look into Azure Portal shows nothing. But if you wait some time (minimum 30 secs, but up to 20!! minutes) the group suddenly appears.

The same also applies if you create a user in Azure through Graph. If you do this, you'll get back an object with the azure id. If you immediately try to add this user to a group or a directory role, it can also happen to get an error, but the timeout here is normally somewhere below 2 sec and I've never seen something above 10 secs.

So for everything, where I'm going to create something in Graph and immediately try to use it, I build some helper method, that tries it multiple times with some smaller timeout between each call:

```
internal static class Multiple
{
    public static Task Try<TException>(int maxRetries, TimeSpan interval, Func<Task> task)
        where TException : Exception
    {
        return Try<TException>(maxRetries, interval, task, exception => true);
    }

    public static async Task Try<TException>(int maxRetries, TimeSpan interval, Func<Task> task, Func<TException, bool> isExpectedException)
        where TException : Exception
    {
        do
        {
            try
            {
                await task().ConfigureAwait(false);
                return;
            }
            catch (Exception ex) when (ex.GetType() == typeof(TException) && isExpectedException((TException)ex))
            {
                maxRetries--;

                if (maxRetries <= 0)
                    throw;

                await Task.Delay(interval);
            }
        } while (true);
    }
}
```

The usage of the class is as follows:

```
await Multiple.Try<ServiceException>(20, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), async () =>
{
    educationClass = await serviceClient.Education.Classes[groupId.ToString()].Request().GetAsync();
}, ex => ex.Error.Code == "Request_ResourceNotFound");
```

This helper will call the inner method up to 20 times with a timeout of one second. Also the thrown exception must have the given error code. If the number of retries is exceeded or a different error is thrown, the call will rethrow the original exception and must be handled on a higher level.

Simply be aware that behind the Graph interface a highly distributed system works and it sometimes needs some time to get everything in sync.

Comment: In other words the API is not designed properly. It's nice that the system is distributed, but the API should be more usable. At the very least it should consistently return 404 for resources not available yet.

Comment: @Ian: In short: You're right. But I think the problem is, that on a few places the system can't distinguish between if something isn't (yet) there or you're not allowed to access it and so producing this wrong answer.

Comment: I can't imagine writing an API like this myself and not attempting to provide some feedback mechanism in the response about the completeness of the action. There was probably a conversation that went something like this:

Dev: we could poll for completeness status then return
Manager: that would make response times longer and use our resources
Dev: yeah, that's because this action takes long
Manager: Nah, let's not do that
Dev: Ok let's document it on the web
Manager: Nah, that would make people think our API is bad
Dev (in his head): yes because you're making it that way

Answer (score 1):

I test it in my side and met same issues with yours. The 403 error should be a bug as you mentioned because I also have the permission to do the operation. But you mentioned that add guest user to owner, I test it with bad request response, I think it is by design.

Since you can request success after waiting 60 seconds, I think the solution is add a `while` loop in your code to request the graph api multiple times. In the `while` loop, if request fail, wait 10 seconds then request again(as Flydog57 mentioned in comments). But you also need to add a mechanism to break loop when request always fail in your code to avoid infinite loops.