# How to determinate that the channel is ready to use in Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

Steps:

1. I create a private channel with 2 members using Teams UI.
2. I try to get a newly created channel by Graph API: [GET /teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http).
3. It responds: `404`.
4. After a while ~2-3 minutes, it responds `200`.
5. I list members of a channel: [GET /teams/{team-id}/channels/{channel-id}/members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)
   .
6. It returns all team members, even those who are not members of the channel.
7. After a while ~2-3 minutes. It returns 2 members, as expected.

It is clear because of ["delay between Graph API and Teams Client"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67077990/should-i-have-to-wait-after-creating-team-with-graph)

There is a workaround about pt. 1-4, we can retry with delay, but it is not clear how we can deal with getting all team members instead only of private channel members.

How can we determine that channel is ready to use? Maybe there is a convenient way to know that everything is propagated completely.

Comment: Can you see when a channel is created and then (after step 4) check if more than 3 minutes have passed? I agree that this is not as you would expect the API to behave...

Comment: I can, but I cannot be sure, that it will be a stable solution.

Comment: We tried the above issue at our end and it worked fine without delays. Private channel creation should be synchronous. Could you please share the following details(requestIds, timestamps, teamthreadid, channelthreadid etc) of the recent create and the read with 404s and 200s. Also please share the details of threadid, members returned when you list the members. Please share these details at - microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com.

Comment: @MaksymKryvchun - Could you please share the above details?

Comment: Sure. Next week, I will prepare the data, thank you.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT I cannot reproduce it now, everything works perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT I was able to reproduce pt. 6-7. I send details to the email. Message subject: "StackOverflow graph channel members API issue [72767663]".

Comment: Thank you for the details, we will check the shared details and get back to you.

Comment: we do not have anything to share currently. we will keep you posted once we have an update. Thank you.

Comment: Engineering has asked if you are still facing this issue? If yes could you please help by sharing a recent repro as well with timestamp and request ids. Could you please share the following details(requestIds, timestamps, teamthreadid, channelthreadid etc) of the recent create and the read with 404s and 200s. Also please share the details of threadid, members returned when you list the members. Please share these details at - microsoftteamsdev@microsoft.com.

Comment: We received the details of a recent repro. We will check and update you. Thank you.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT I face only the second part (5-7). The number of members is not correct just after the channel creation. I sent the details. The title of email is `StackOverflow graph channel members API issue [72767663]`.

Comment: @MaksymKryvchun - Can you please let us know if you are still facing this issue? Engineering team has made a fix for this issue. I cannot verify the fix as I could not repro this issue since the beginning.